# When can we expect a stable version of Redis Cluster

Tags: redis

Looks like Redis cluster support is in active development at this stage. Any idea when a stable version would be released with full cluster support?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the latest from antirez, ["in three weeks"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/_DqcFW8EAOA/MD4tFqeye6EJ) on Jan 13th, 2015 -> expected around Feb 3rd, 2015.